# POSIX shell equivalent of bash "declare -p"

Tags: bash, sh

I'm writing a POSIX shell function based on bash `declare -p` behaviour, the difference being that it targets POSIX shells.

I've set a few goals:

1. **Make a robust function**
   => OK for the current code (I think).
2. **Don't define any variable** (to avoid clashes)
   => OK, the current implementation doesn't define any variable
3. **As little as possible forks**
   => Currently 2 forks. A single one would be great, but I'm not sure that it is possible without defining any variable.
4. **A return status of 1 when an invalid variable name is given as argument**
   => <s>That's not currently the case</s> The current behavior is to process the good arguments and to skip the invalid ones (printing an error message and setting the return status to 1), just like `declare -p` does.

<s>My current problem is in **#4** but any advice about the other points is welcome ;-)</s>

Here's the code. The first `awk` validates the arguments and generates a shell command for updating `$@`, which is then processed with `eval`. The second `awk` will then print the variables declarations with single-quote escaping:

<sub>**edit:** fixed the code based on @thatotherguy suggestion</sub>

```sh
#!/bin/sh

declare_p() {
    eval "$(
        awk -v funcname="declare_p" '
            BEGIN {
                output = "set --"
                for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {
                    if (ARGV[i] ~ /^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*$/) {
                        output = output" "ARGV[i]" \042\044"ARGV[i]"\042"
                    } else {
                        print funcname": "ARGV[i]": not a valid identifier" > "/dev/stderr"
                        error = 1
                        # exit 1
                    }
                }
                print output
                exit
            }
            END { if (error) print "false" }
        ' -- "$@"
    )" # || return 1
    awk -v rc="$?" '
        BEGIN {
            for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i += 2) {
                gsub(/\047/,"\047\134\047\047",ARGV[i+1])
                print ARGV[i] "=" "\047" ARGV[i+1] "\047"
            }
            exit rc
        }
    ' -- "$@"
}
```

###### Example

```sh
#!/bin/sh

var1=" a  b "
var2="a'b"
var3="a
b"
var4="
"

declare_p var1 var2 var3 var4 var-x
echo "return code: $?"
```

output:

```
declare_p: var-x: not a valid identifier # (stderr)
var1=' a  b '
var2='a'\''b'
var3='a
b'
var4='
'
return code: 1
```

Comment: You could have your awk function print `return 1` in case of error to have the `eval` execute it, or add the return code to the returned list so that you can check `$1` and either return or shift it off

Comment: @thatotherguy Great!! Thanks to your advice I thought of an other trick which is to print a `false` in the first `awk` then pass a `-v rc="$?"` to the next one. That would make it easy to change the behaviour of the function by adding a `|| return 1` (or not) after the `eval`

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
declare_p() {
    while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do
       if ! printf %s "$1" | grep -qx '[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'; then
             echo "declare_p: Invalid variable name: $1" >&2
             return 1
       fi
       printf "%s='%s'\n" "$1" "$(
            eval "printf %s \"\$$1\"" |
            sed "s/'/'\\\\''/"
       )"
       shift
    done
}

# unit test
var=$(seq 255 | xargs printf %02x\\n | xxd -r -p)
eval "$(var2="$var" ; declare_p var2)"
if [ "$var" = "$var2" ]; then echo FINE; fi
```

Sure, you could optimize `sed` and `grep` to some magic awk - I do not think it's worth the time, if you want performance use a different programming language.

Comment: Well, writing a POSIX C program should be easy enough, but then I'll have to compile it on each target system; I don't it think it's a waste of time to write a shell function that you can rely on afterwards. BTW your validation step lacks a test for linefeed, and you `return 1`  once you find an invalid identifier, which is a plausible behavior but not the one in my question. +1

Comment: For not stripping the trailing linefeeds in the values I would remove the single-quotes in the `"%s='%s'\\n"` and add `| { printf \'; cat; printf \'; }` after the sed